# Apply margin in case an input element goes to the next line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline form in Bootstrap. At a certain resolution (above 768px after which the form goes all vertical, by default), one of the input elements goes to the next line. Then, after that, (also above 768px) another element goes down.

Here's the thing: I want to be able to control what happens in case the first and the second element go down. For eg, I want to add a margin-top to the first element that goes down. Is there a way to accomplish this in Bootstrap? So far the only thing I've tried is to a) Detect at exactly what pixel width the specific element goes to the next line b) Write a CSS in a media query, for eg:

```
@media (max-width: 1205px ) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .mg-up {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Or maybe another solution would be to keep them however small so they fit horizontally, until 768px?

Comment: would ```!important``` work?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, since the CSS properties are determined by the media query. Applying a margin based on the media query seems to be the reasonable thing to do, and it's something I would do myself if I faced this problem.

Few suggestions:

1. Co-locate the `margin` media query rule with the media query for the inline/block behaviour of the form input elements. This is to remind you (and other people working on it) that they are related. If they are part of Bootstrap by default, then forget about it.
2. If you are using Sass, read the `$grid-breakpoints` variable from `_variables.scss` (in Bootstrap 4) and use that value instead so that the two styling behaviours will stay in sync.